# javascript: disable re-writing object methods

Tags: javascript, methods, url-rewriting

Is there any way to disable the rewriting on methods on javascript objects?

For example :

```
var myObj=new Object();
myObj.doSomething=function(){
 alert("good message")
}

myObj.doSomething=function(){
 alert("bad message")
}

myObj.doSomething(); // I want to alert me with "good message"
```

I think this can be done , cause I wanted to to rewrite a method a few years ago, and I received an error in javascript console about that method has only get and not set.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ECMAScript 5 you can set objects to be [unmodifiable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze):

```
Object.freeze(myObj);
```

You can create an individual property that can't be modified using:

```
Object.createProperty(myObj, 'name', descriptor);
```

where `descriptor` is itself an [object containing flags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty), one of which is `configurable` which if set to `false` prevents that property from being changed or deleted.

Comment: you can also use `Object.seal`

Comment: While you are correct, it should be noted (however sadly) that a frighteningly large number of browsers in the wild are still running on ECMAScript-262 3rd Edition and its various implementations. If you're looking for portability, the existence of freeze and seal cannot be relied upon.

Comment: @Mike yes, absolutely. I _did_ qualify this in the very first line ;-).   As far as I know there's no standard solution in earlier editions.

Comment: I did not mean to imply that you had not; I merely mean to *highlight* the portability issue. I probably should have just kept my fingers off the keyboard. :)

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is designed around the notion that *anything* can be changed. You can override the functionality of just about *anything*, *anywhere*, at *any* time.

This is both a blessing and a curse.

If you ran into that error message, it was likely either (a) a bug in a JavaScript/JScript implementation, or (b) not what you thought it was.

AMMENDED: It's possible you were looking at ECMAScript 5 code. I've been maintaining ECMAScript 3 for so long I've apparently developed cataracts that blind me to that possibility. Forgive me. I stand humbly corrected.

Comment: yes. I think it was ECMAScript 5 , cause I needed the latest version of Mozilla rhino to run the scripts. That time I didn't give much about that error.

Answer (score 0):

While Alnitak has a nice direct answer to your question, depending on what you are trying to accomplish you may be able to prevent 're-writing' a method by making it a 'private' variable through a closure.  It won't protect 'public' functions, but can hide private ones and prevent them from being modified.

```
var myObj = (function(){
    var data = {count: 0};
    var privateFunction1 = function(){
      data.count++;
    };

    var privateFunction2 = function(){
      // do something else
    };

    var result = {
        callPrivateFunction: function(){
            privateFunction();
            privateFunction2();
        }
    };

    return result;
})();
```

Of course, any public function that calls the private function is re-writable, so depending on what you're trying to accomplish the may just be pushing the problem around.  However, this approach is a nice way to accomplish some encapsulation and not present more in the API of the object than you want.

Comment: thanks. it's a nice example. I was thought about this first time, however is not helping in what I want to accomplish, because is like you said, you can rewrite the public functions that calls the private ones.